# Error When Deploying Webapp on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am having some trouble deploying a webapp on tomcat. I keep getting the following error.

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/SadScary.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed         to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SadScary]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:208)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Any ideas what might be causing this exception? I have checked and re-checked my web-xml and servlet mappings and I cannot find any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit.. Here is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" id="WebApp_ID"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<display-name>SadScary</display-name>
<listener>
  <listener-class>
  com.example.reelchatterap.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
  <description>Reviews Database</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myTestDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>UpdateList</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
  com.example.reelchatterap.UpdateList</servlet-class>
</servlet>-
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>UpdateList</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/UpdateList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping></web-app>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? check logs/catalina.out and provide us with some additional info :)

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. The above was taken from the logs. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this error is just suggesting a misconfiguration of your web.xml file. Perhaps posting your web.xml might help us figuring ou the issue.

Comment: Thanks BelgianMyWaffle. I'll edit to include my web.xml now.